# How can I install a previous version of ICU?

Tags: software-installation, 16.04

In 16.04 LTS the current ICU version is 55.

I need to install version 52 to run a specific piece of software to convert a database.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

---

It's a general thing that some software will require a particular version of libicu , and also that having more than one version is without issues : 
All files have unique names : libicudata.so.52, etc.

So you can often just install a package without conflicts. icu52 : http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libicu52&searchon=names → libicu52

---

Comment: but you still can't install libicu52 from repo in 16.04 as it's not there...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [source package page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/icu/52.1-8) for a 52* `icu` version on launchpad.

Under **Builds** click your architecture: amd64 for 64-bit systems, i386 for 32-bit, and so on.

Scroll down on the architecture-specific page to **Built files** and find the `.deb` packages.

Save the files in a directory by themselves, then `cd` to the directory and do

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

This will install *over* higher versions.

Just be aware in general that downgrading packages like this could cause problems if other programs depend on those higher versions, because `dpkg` doesn't do dependency checks when downgrading (see `man dpkg`)